# Repetitive instruction but use of for loop does not seem possible

Tags: for-loop, recursion

I need to prompt the user to ask several questions. I don't know in advance how many questions she will ask. How do I code for this? Should I use a for loop? A for loop does not seem possible. It seems like the only way is to hard code this, which does not seem ideal. Thank you in advance.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int numberQuestions;
  

    char sentenceOne[81], sentenceTwo[81], sentenceThree[81], sentenceFour[81], sentenceFive[81];

    // ask user how many questions she wants to ask
    printf("How many questions?\n");
    scanf(" %d", &numberQuestions);

    if(numberQuestions ==1)
    {
       printf("enter question number One\n");
       scanf(" %s", sentenceOne);
    }
    else if (numberQuestions ==2)
    {
        printf("enter question number One\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceOne);

        printf("enter question number Two\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceTwo);
    }
    else if (numberQuestions == 3)
    {
        printf("enter question number One\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceOne);

        printf("enter question number Two\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceTwo);

        printf("enter question number Three\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceThree);
    }
    else if (numberQuestions == 4)
    {
        printf("enter question number One\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceOne);

        printf("enter question number Two\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceTwo);

        printf("enter question number Three\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceThree);

        printf("enter question number Four\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceFour);
    }
    else if (numberQuestions == 5)
    {
        printf("enter question number One\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceOne);

        printf("enter question number Two\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceTwo);

        printf("enter question number Three\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceThree);

        printf("enter question number Four\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceFour);

        printf("enter question number Five\n");
        scanf(" %s", sentenceFive);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may not seem possible because you might not know about arrays yet. Do you? The approach is like this: `char *digitWords[] = {"one", "two", ...};` and `char *sentences[5]`. YOu can use `malloc` or [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) if you're not sure in advance how much to allow. Imagine if you had 100 or 10000 questions. So, yes, it's possible. BTW, this has nothing to do with recursion.

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful. I wonder if you can have a look at the following link. I have half implmented your advice and it seems to work a little but I think I need more help. If you can help, please do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672235/how-do-i-use-scanf-within-a-loop-to-read-a-string